# Find all matches in a string from list of possibilities in array

Tags: arrays, regex, powershell

I have the body of an email (at this point in the code, it's just a string), and an array of words I need to find. I'm trying to get an array of words that were in the email from the array of words. For example:

```
$wordsArray = "foo|bar|regex|powershell"
$emailBody = "This is an email body written into a string, without breaks. foo regex."
```

And from that I expect to receive

```
@("foo", "regex")
```

Case doesn't matter, order doesn't matter, etc.

Right now I have this function:

```
function func($emailBody, $wordsArray) {
    $matched= @()
    $matched+= $emailBody| Select-String $wordsArray -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }

    return $matched | sort -Unique
```

}

However this function grows at an incredible rate. I loop over multiple emails, the first time I run it, it's at 0.05287 seconds, the 30th run is 0.11733 seconds, the 45th run is 1.72352 seconds, and the 50th is over 5 seconds. I have to run this 40,000 times (and growing).

Any tips?

Comment: can you include the rest of your code? I don't see why the run time for the function you posted would increase on multiple uses.

Comment: @ctwheels I'm not interfacing with any webmail objects, at this point in the script, it's a raw string. You could just totally replace "email" with "randomString", and I'd have the same question.

Comment: @AxelPersinger add that information to your question to prevent any further confusion

Answer (score 1):

See if this doesn't speed up the process:

```
$wordsFound = @{}
filter AddWord { $wordsFound[$_]++ }
$wordsArray = @("foo", "bar", "regex", "powershell")
$regex = ‘(?i)^(‘ + (($wordsArray |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)$’

$emailBody = "This is an email, without breaks. foo regex."
$emailBody -split '\W' -match $regex | AddWord

$wordsFound.getenunumerator().Name | sort
```

That creates an alternating regex from your word array, then splits the email body at the word boundaries creating an array of words in the email, and matches it against the regex.  Since you're using `-match` as an array operator it will act as a filter, passing through all of the words that matched the regex in a single operation.

Edit: added an example of using a hash table as an in-stream de-duping mechanism.

Comment: It cut the time in half, but it still grows exponentially. Which makes no sense to me, but it's definitely growing without a matching grow of body size

Comment: What does your memory consumption look like?  Are you accumulating all the words from all the emails before you do that sort to de-dupe them? If that array is getting big it may be eating you up in memory management and you might be off using a hash table to de-dupe them in-stream. I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: The email strings actually come from a list of SharePoint objects which is going to be pretty large, and I just pass the strings to this function. I monitored mem consumption and didn't see any major spikes or anything. I tried out your edit and it didn't seem to have any improvements, unfortunately. @mjolinor

Comment: About the only advice I have at this point is to start adding some measure-command  lines at various points in the process and see if they'll tell you where the bottleneck is developing.